# Why Flutter's withNewEngine cannot be recognized?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I am working on a form-based application. It is time-consuming when we create forms natively. I want to see am I able to create a sample form in the Flutter app and then import it to my native android project.

I created a Flutter module and added a few form views to it. I am able to build aar file by this command:

`$ flutter build aar`.

Then I followed [Integrate a Flutter module into your Android project](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) document. I added the following lines in the `settings.gradle` file at root of the native project:

```
setBinding(new Binding([gradle:this]))
evaluate(new File(
        settingsDir.parentFile,
        'site_finder_flutter/.android/include_flutter.groovy'
))
```

I have `site_finder_flutter` side by side of my native android project, `site_finder_android`. So, I don't get any error regarding the above `evaluate` function.

Then, I added the following line in the app/build.gradle file of the native project.

```
android {
  //...
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
  }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':flutter')
...
}
```

I want to launch my Flutter screen when I click on a button. So, this is its code:

```
llTestFlutter.setOnClickListener {
  FlutterActivity
    .withNewEngine()
    .initialRoute("/")
    .build(this)
}
```

`FlutterActivity` could be recognized automatically and I imported the class. However, `withNewEngine` can't be recognized.

[image]

What do you think?

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 1.22.1 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f30b7f4db9 (6 days ago) • 2020-10-08 10:06:30 -0700
Engine • revision 75bef9f6c8
Tools • Dart 2.10.1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG, I think I realized what was the issue. Android suggested two option for importing the `FlutterActivity`:

1. import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity
2. import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity

I had chosen the first option first. That's why that method was not here. I chose the second import and the problem's gone.